# How do I tar ball a directory hierarchy with soft links in Linux?

Tags: linux, tar

How do I tar ball/compress a directory hierarchy with soft links in Linux?

Comment: Do you want the final tarbal to have the soft-links or the target file of those links. It's unclear in your question.

Answer (score 42):

GNU tar normally includes symlinks in the tarball it generates. If you want it to include the file the symlink points to instead then pass it `-h`/`--dereference` when creating the tarball.

Answer (score 18):

When used with standard arguments `tar xvf`,
the soft links are saved in the tar archive as soft-links. 
Then there are two cases:

- If your symlink is a full pathname, it might be broken when untarred.
- If your symlink is a relative pathname, under the folder you are tarring,
  it will work fine when extracted.

If you want to tar the file and not the symlink, you can use the `-h / --dereference` arguments.

Comment: And how is that different from another answer, which as well doesn't work?

Comment: @EugZol It works but you need to add `h` before `f`. So `tar -hxvf` for instance.

Comment: shouldn't it be `tar -hcvf` in order to create an archive?

Answer (score 1):

Just another way, using /etc as an example:

```bash
find /etc | cpio -puvdm . ; tar czf ttt.tgz etc
rm -rf etc
tar xvzf ttt.tgz
ls -l etc/rc*
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also a site [tour] and a [help].

Comment: Please note the conventions for formatting [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML](http://superuser.com/help/formatting).