# Does tar preserve links?

Tags: linux, unix, solaris, tar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I tar ball a directory hierarchy with soft links in linux](https://superuser.com/questions/137388/how-can-i-tar-ball-a-directory-hierarchy-with-soft-links-in-linux)

I am using tar to copy files and directories from a Solaris machine to a Linux machine.

- Does Tar preserve the Symbolic Links, Hard links and those links which uses absolute paths?

I am copying the Directories one by one from the root, I am not copying the entire `/` to the new server as I already have few directories setup.

Comment: What did you find out when you tried a small example test?

Comment: Can you clarify what your expectations are. "preserving links" can be understood different ways, especially referring to "those links which use absolute paths".

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tar), at least for gnu tar:

```
   -h, --dereference
          follow symlinks; archive and dump the files 
          they point to

   --hard-dereference
          follow hard links; archive and dump the files 
          they refer to
```

Answer (score 1):

generally speaking it depends on tar implementations and command line options.

GNU tar has options for that http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_node/hard-links.html

I would like to recommend you use cpio instead of tar. cpio format is more portable across UNIX-es and cpio preserves hard links

Answer (score 0):

It can, depending on the options you do/don't give it. Also, with regard to hard links, it will only preserve the hard links within the data set you are currently working with - e.g. if you have a hard link between a file in directory `a/` linking to a file in `b/`, but you're only archiving/unpacking `a/`, then it won't preserve that link.

Answer (score 0):

You should try Rsync in this case.